# fragments not displaying in framelayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

**Intro:**

To put things into perspective, I am attempting to use fragments to create a Sudoku game.

The Sudoku board consists of 9 sub-grids, each containing 9 cells, so 9 cells in one grid, and 9 of these grids form the Sudoku board, arranged in a 3x3 fashion.

[image]

---

**Method:**

Home screen containing some information, of which a `GridLayout` contains 9 `Framelayout`s where each Sudoku Fragment will be placed into

The 9 Sudoku Fragments will make up the Sudoku board.

`sudoku_cell` extends a `LinearLayout` with an `onClickListener`, since extending a TextView, I was unable to inflate the `sudoku_cell` layout (*Is it possible to do so?*)

In my main activity, I have a GridLayout containing 9 FrameLayouts. These layouts have column and row locations set to form a 3x3 matrix, this is where each of the fragments will be added into.

These FrameLayouts are named on a 0-based index: `frame00`, `frame01`, `frame02`, `frame10`, etc

---

**Documentation says:**

As mentioned here on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), I am required to have an:

- Inflator method for the fragment, i.e. `onCreateView()` which inflates the fragment
- A `Layout` container of sorts to root/place the fragment in, in the main activity (in my case)
- A `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransactionManager` to handle the fragments, adding and commiting them.

---

**Problem:**

**TL;DR:** Simply, my fragments are not showing.

After calling the `commit()`, I expect to see a 3x3 board of `sudoku_grid` fragments, each containing 9 `sudoku_cell`s. However, this does not get shown

I have searched SO, reread the documentation, and searched more but cannot understand why it is not showing.

---

**I have tried:**

When inflating my fragment, I inflate a `sudoku_cell` layout instead, this does infact show a 9 cell grid.

However each cell should be a grid containing 9 cells, this leads me to believe that there may be an issue on the `Sudoku_Grid` - `Sudoku_Cell` side, possibly the `sudoku_cell` layout is not being inflated correctly or being rooted correctly.

Usually an `LayoutInflator`, and `ViewGroup` is passed allowing one to inflate a layout, but in the case of the `sudoku_cell`, I cannot find such a method to `override`, is this the cause?

---

**The code:**

**sudoku_cell.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cellText"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="1px"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/clBlack">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**SudokuCell.java**

```
public class SudokuCell extends LinearLayout{

    private LinearLayout layout;
    private TextView textView;
    private Context mContext;
    private Point location;
    private int index;

    public SudokuCell(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SudokuCell(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sudoku_cell, this, true);

        textView = layout.findViewById(R.id.cellText);
        setText("");
    }

    public void setStaticText(String s){
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setText(s);
            textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
        }
    }

    public void setText(String s){
        if (textView != null)
            textView.setText(s);
    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

9 of these `sudoku_cell`'s get added to a `sudoku_grid` as shown below in the `onCreateView()` and `populateGrid()` methods:

**sudoku_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2px"
        android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3">

</GridLayout>
```

**SudokuGrid.java**

```
public class SudokuGrid extends Fragment{

    private GridLayout gridLayout;
    private List<GridFragmentListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mActitityContext;
    private boolean FRAGMENT_LOCATION_CENTRE;
    private float SCREEN_DP;
    private int GRID_MARGINS_DP = 1;
    private int colorOdd, colorEven;
    private List<Integer> presetGrid;
    private View previousView;
    private Drawable previousViewDrawable;

    public void addGridListener(GridFragmentListener gridFragmentListener) {
        listeners.add(gridFragmentListener);
    }

    public void removeGridListener(GridFragmentListener gridFragmentListener) {
        listeners.remove(gridFragmentListener);
    }

    protected void notifyValueChanged(View value) {
        for (GridFragmentListener listener : listeners) listener.onValueChange(value);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mActitityContext = getActivity();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sudoku_grid, container, false);

        //set grid view
        gridLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

        populateGrid();
        return v;
    }

    private void populateGrid() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            SudokuCell sudokuCell = new SudokuCell(mActitityContext);
            sudokuCell.setBackgroundColor(((i % 2) == 0) ? R.color.clOdd : R.color.clEven);
            System.out.printf("Sudoku Cell ID [ index = " + String.valueOf(i) + " ] - getId() = " + sudokuCell.getId());
            sudokuCell.setLocation(getPoint(i));
            sudokuCell.setIndex(i);
            sudokuCell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    notifyValueChanged(view);
                }
            });
            sudokuCell.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                    SudokuCell cell = (SudokuCell) view;
                    if (b)
                        view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActitityContext, R.color.clSelected));
                    else
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActitityContext, (cell.getIndex() % 2 == 0) ? R.color.clOdd : R.color.clEven));
                }
            });
            sudokuCell.setStaticText(String.valueOf(i));
            gridLayout.addView(sudokuCell, i);
        }
    }

    private Point getPoint(int i) {
        int y = 0;
        while (i > 2){
            y++;
            i -= 3;
        }
        return new Point(i, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            addGridListener((GridFragmentListener) getActivity());
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(
                    getActivity().getClass().toString()
                            + " does not implement the DetailsFragment.DetailsFragmentListener interface.");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        removeGridListener((GridFragmentListener) getActivity());
    }
}
```

In my main activity, I handle the creation of 9 `sudoku_grid` fragments which are placed into each respective `FrameLayout`, to form a 3x3 matrix of `Sudoku_Grid`s, which will form the Sudoku board

**activity_main_sudoku.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="wrap302.nmu.task1.MainActivitySudoku"
        android:background="@color/clDarkGrey">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:text="@string/app_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/clWhite"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="@string/lblScore"
                android:textColor="@color/clWhite"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/lblScore"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button" android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:id="@+id/main_sudokugrid_container">
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/clWhite"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frame00"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/clWhite"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frame01"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/clWhite"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frame02"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/clWhite"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frame10"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/clWhite"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frame11"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/clWhite"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frame12"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/clWhite"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frame20"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/clWhite"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frame21"/>
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/clWhite"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frame22"/>
    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="0dp">
            <Button
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:text="1"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:text="2"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn3"
                    android:text="3"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn4"
                    android:text="4"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn5"
                    android:text="5"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn6"
                    android:text="6"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn7"
                    android:text="7"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn8"
                    android:text="8"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btn9"
                    android:text="9"/>
            <Button
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:layout_rowSpan="3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                    android:text="Clear"/>
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivitySudoku.java**

```
public class MainActivitySudoku extends AppCompatActivity implements GridFragmentListener {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_sudoku);
        createSudokuGrid();
    }

    private void createSudokuGrid() {
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionManager = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransactionManager.add(R.id.frame00, new SudokuGrid());
        fragmentTransactionManager.add(R.id.frame01, new SudokuGrid());
        fragmentTransactionManager.add(R.id.frame02, new SudokuGrid());
        fragmentTransactionManager.add(R.id.frame10, new SudokuGrid());
        fragmentTransactionManager.add(R.id.frame11, new SudokuGrid());
        fragmentTransactionManager.add(R.id.frame12, new SudokuGrid());
        fragmentTransactionManager.add(R.id.frame20, new SudokuGrid());
        fragmentTransactionManager.add(R.id.frame21, new SudokuGrid());
        fragmentTransactionManager.add(R.id.frame22, new SudokuGrid());

        fragmentTransactionManager.commit();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Activity Started & Viewable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // GridFragmentListener
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(View view) {
        //todo something here with received view
    }
}
```

Comment: I am seeing my main activity, this contains the title, score label and buttons with an empty space in the middle. i.e. everything excepts the fragments

Comment: @YvetteColomb yes, 1 gridlayout containing FrameLayouts and the other form my buttons. The first gridlayout we are concerned with as this is where the fragments should appear/be placed in.

Comment: @YvetteColomb yes, the buttons are displaying, the fragments not (which should contain sudoku_grid fragments)

Comment: @YvetteColomb to avoid a discussion, this is part of an assignment for my university course, the aim of which is to use `fragments` with alternate `layouts`, `locales`, `sharedpreferences`, etc. Once again, thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution proved simpler than expected.

In short, the solution was to move the SudokuCell constructor code from the

```
SudokuCell(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

to the

```
SudokuCell(Context context)
```

since that was the constructor I was calling.

A few other changes can be made for improvement, this solves the fragments not being displayed.

*Quite a simple error*

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I have given you a sample of how to add your fragments so they will display. If you go through this and emulate the process this will assist you. I've used basic examples in the layout so we can have ids to use in the classes.

You'll also need to manage the app lifecycle and the back press button on how you want to manage your stack with your fragments and maintaining any data.

Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Fragment fragment;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_myactivity);
        View view = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frag);

        fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Layout for Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                .../...>
    .../...

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag"
        // sort out your layout here with the frameLayouts
        android:layout_below="@+id/your_id"
    />
    .../...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment

```
public class MyFragmentextends Fragment {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    Fragment fragment;


    public static MyFragmentnewInstance(String item {
        fragment =
                new MyFragment();
        // pass data from activity
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ITEM, item);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public DeliveryDisplayFromDispenserFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            item = getArguments().getString(ITEM);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Layout for Fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        .../...>

    // fragment layout
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for providing a basic framework of fragments, also noting that one should manage the fragment stack and restore data, however I have found the solution. I will still incorporate that which you mentioned in bettering my application, thank you!